# Qt Creator Ubuntu version weird compiler error

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, qt-creator

I'm just trying to test some methods in `OpenCV` using `Qt` in Ubuntu version and I'm running into some compilers problems where I'm stuck.

```
Mat imageSpecularReflectorRemoved ,edgesImage;
Mat img_object = imread(patternImageName);
removeSpecuralReflector(img_object,imageSpecularReflectorRemoved);
applyLaplacian(img_object, edgesImage);

std::vector <cv::Mat> listOfImagesToDisplay;
listOfImagesToDisplay.push_back(img_object);
listOfImagesToDisplay.push_back(imageSpecularReflectorRemoved);
listOfImagesToDisplay.push_back(edgesImage);
ImagesUtility imgUtil;
cv::Mat fullImage = imgUtil.makeCanvas(listOfImagesToDisplay,400,1);
```

Here the is the interface file of the ImagesUtility class (.h file)

```
 class ImagesUtility
    {
    public:
        ImagesUtility();
        cv::Mat makeCanvas(std::vector<cv::Mat> vecMat, int windowHeight, int nRows);
    };
```

Here is the cpp file of the ImagesUtility class

```
ImagesUtility::ImagesUtility()
{

}

cv::Mat makeCanvas(std::vector<cv::Mat> vecMat, int windowHeight, int nRows)
{

    return canvasImage;
}
```

The compiler error is:
[image]

Any idea what's going on here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
cv::Mat ImagesUtility::makeCanvas(std::vector<cv::Mat> vecMat, int windowHeight, int nRows)
{

    return canvasImage;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem last week. You should add `ImagesUtility::` to the `makeCanvas` method in your cpp file.